# Смена стандартной директории etc/www apache

Tags: apache, php, sql-server

Есть установленые apache + php на дебиан. Понадобилось сменить директорию с сайтом /etc/www/site на /media/sf_www - расшареную папку.
в фалике /etc/apache2/sites-available/site добавил следущее:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName portal.irbi
  ServerAlias www.portal.irbi
  DocumentRoot "/media/sf_www"
  <Directory "/media/sf_www">
    allow from all
    Options +Indexes
  </Directory>
  AssignUserId zhukov vboxsf
</VirtualHost>
```

Сайт работает нормально, php код тоже работает, но теперь не может подключится к mssql который стоит на хостовой машине, пишет - сервер не найден, хотя когда сайт лежал в папке /ect/www/site к mssql нормально подключался

Comment: раз не может подключиться, значит что то пишет в лог. Для хостовой машины в принципе побоку, с какого каталога запускается скрипт.

Comment: Проблема решена, оказалось айпишник менялся динамически у хостовой ОС.